# Don't return object if undefined?

Tags: javascript, object, undefined

I'm hoping someone might be able to help out here, or point me in the right direction.

1. I'm using an external API, to find out which flights are available, on which days. (Response is `mm_newJson`).
2. I'm then creating a new object `obj = {};`, to store/push the values I need for each day, (the `date` and `fare`).
3. And then, I'm matching the `obj.date` to my calendar days, and inserting the `fare` value, whenever there is a value.

For some days, there are no values in my object.  And therefore, returns `undefined`.

Here's a screenshot, of what my object looks like, in this scenario:

[image]

**The problem:**

Where the object is `undefined`, (because there is no object.date or object.fare key/values), I do not want the object.fare to be inserted into my calendar.

In this scenario, "undefined" appears in my calendar.

I've patched up this issue, by replacing "undefined", with an empty string `" "` .  But basically, I just don't want object.fare to be returned at all, if it is undefined.

My code is below and I have tried adding my conditions in the function below.  Eg:

`if (typeof object === 'object')`, or
`if (object == 'undefined')`, or

My however, I'm not sure how to resolve this.

I just don't want the object.value to be inserted, if it is undefined.  As undefined appears on the matching calendar days, when I don't want it to.

```
window.mm_newJson = [];
window.mm_dailyPrice = [];
window.mm_fullDate = new Date();
window.mm_startDate = String(mm_fullDate.getFullYear()) + '-' + String(mm_fullDate.getMonth()+1) + '-' +  String(mm_fullDate.getDate());

// FETCH DATE AVAILABILITY
const response = await fetch('https://www.MYAPI.COM');
mm_newJson = await response.json();

// Loope through API to find each month
for (let i=0; i < mm_newJson.Months.length; i++) {
  console.log(mm_newJson.Months[i].FlightDates);

  // Find fares which are available in month
  for (let j = 0; j < mm_newJson.Months[i].FlightDates.length; j++) {
    let obj = {};
    // Grab the specific dates
    obj['date'] = String(mm_newJson.Months[i].YearNumber) + '-' + String(('0' + String(mm_newJson.Months[i].MonthNumber)).slice(-2)) + '-' + String(('0' + (mm_newJson.Months[i].FlightDates[j])).slice(-2));
    obj['fare'] = "WW";
    mm_dailyPrice.push(obj);
  };
};

// Search mm_dailyPrice for date
function searchDate(input) {
  let object = mm_dailyPrice.find(el => el.date === input);
  console.log("object", object)
  if (object != undefined) {
    return object.fare;
  } else {
    // Returns undefined, if I do not handle else condition
    return "n/a";
  }
};


// Add AVAILABILITY
let days = document.querySelector('div[data-tab*="Date Calendar Outbound"]').querySelectorAll('.day');
let j = 0;

// For each day in the 12 month calendar, display the "fare" value
for (let i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
  let date = days[i].dataset.date;
  if (days[i].firstElementChild){
    let fare = searchDate(date);

    // if (fare !== "undefined") {
      console.log("fare", fare);
      let priceSpan = document.createElement('span');
      priceSpan.innerHTML = String(fare);
      priceSpan.setAttribute('class', 'calendar-price-test');
      days[j].appendChild(priceSpan);
      j++;
    // }
  }
};
```

Here's how my calendar looks, if the object is undefined, (but in this screenshot, I've replaced undefined with a string, so `undefined` doesn't appear on the relevant day.

But really, I don't want anything for these days to appear at all.  So I don't want object.fare to be identified, if it's undefined.  IE - I don't want it to appear in the calendar.

[image]

**Here's also a screenshot of the response, after the initial fetch, if that helps.  The numbers in `FlightDates`, represents the days of the month, where I'd like to inject "WW" only.**

[image]

Comment: Did you try with `typeof object !== "undefined"`?

Comment: `But basically, I just don't want object.price to be returned at all, if it is undefined.` I don't see `object.price` in your codes. What do you mean?

Comment: @ikhvjs - sorry i meant object.fare

Comment: No worries. But actually the problem is not if the function return a value or not. because you will use the function return value in `let fare = searchDate(date)`. How do you want to set the value of `fare` if the object is `undefined`?

Comment: @AlexandroPalacios - Hiya, I did try that too, but it didn't seem to have any impact.  The result was still the same

Comment: @ikhvjs - thank you for coming back to me.  I actually don't want really need there to be any value at all.  What I want, is to only `days[j].appendChild(priceSpan);`, if the object has values.  Does that make sense?

Because I only want object.fare to appear, for the relevant day in the calendar, if object.fare has a value.

Comment: the `priceSpan` will take the value of `fare` to set the innerHTML.  `priceSpan.innerHTML = String(fare);`  So, the question is what do you want for the innerHTML if the object is `undefined` ?

Comment: @ikhvjs - I guess when the code gets to `priceSpan.innerHTML = String(fare);`, I need to only have returned objects which have a value.  I think the problem might be here   `if (object != undefined) `, where I shouldn't return undefined object?

Comment: @ReenaVerma Since you are returning `"n/a"` when is `undefined`, I think that if you put `if (fare !== "n/a")` you can avoid to append empty fare.

Comment: @AlexandroPalacios - I did try that too, but then for all the days in the calendar, "WW" is inserted

Comment: @ReenaVerma do you have more than one flight for each day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have all the information I need so I hope I can help you (it would be optimal to have a json example of the data returned by the API).

A javascript function can return undefined this way:

```
// Search mm_dailyPrice for date
function searchDate(input) {
  let object = mm_dailyPrice.find(el => el.date === input);
  console.log("object", object)
  if (object != undefined)
    return object.fare;
  
  return;
};
```

But when you check with this line of code (currently commented):

```
if (fare !== "undefined") {
```

you must test for `undefined` not `"undefined"`, or you can test for the latter using `typeof`:

```
if (fare !== undefined) {
```

or

```
if (typeof fare !== "undefined") {
```

Personally I prefer the former, the other one can be confusing.

As you can see your code is working correctly.

```js
window.mm_newJson = [];
window.mm_dailyPrice = [];
window.mm_fullDate = new Date();
window.mm_startDate = String(mm_fullDate.getFullYear()) + '-' + String(mm_fullDate.getMonth()+1) + '-' +  String(mm_fullDate.getDate());

mm_newJson = {
    Months: [
        {MonthNumber: 8, YearNumber: 2021, FlightDates: [4, 6, 15, 18, 20, 22]},
        {MonthNumber: 9, YearNumber: 2021, FlightDates: [4, 5, 6, 8, 12, 13, 15, 16, 14, 19, 20, 22]},
        {MonthNumber: 10, YearNumber: 2021, FlightDates: [3, 5, 6, 8, 12, 13, 15, 16, 14, 19, 20, 22]},
        {MonthNumber: 11, YearNumber: 2021, FlightDates: [3, 6, 8, 13, 16, 18, 20, 22]},
        {MonthNumber: 12, YearNumber: 2021, FlightDates: [3, 5, 6, 8, 12, 13, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20, 22]},
        {MonthNumber: 1, YearNumber: 2022, FlightDates: [2, 5, 6, 8, 12, 13, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20, 22]},
        {MonthNumber: 2, YearNumber: 2022, FlightDates: [2, 5, 6, 8, 12, 13, 16, 18, 17, 24]},
        {MonthNumber: 3, YearNumber: 2022, FlightDates: [2, 5, 6, 8, 11, 13, 15, 18, 17, 24]},
        {MonthNumber: 4, YearNumber: 2022, FlightDates: [1, 5, 6, 8, 11, 13, 15, 16, 17, 25]},
        {MonthNumber: 5, YearNumber: 2022, FlightDates: [1, 5, 6, 8, 10, 13, 15, 16, 18, 25]},
        {MonthNumber: 6, YearNumber: 2022, FlightDates: [1, 5, 6, 8, 10, 13, 15, 16, 18, 25]},
        {MonthNumber: 7, YearNumber: 2022, FlightDates: [1, 5, 6, 8, 10, 13, 15, 16, 18]},
        {MonthNumber: 8, YearNumber: 2022, FlightDates: [1, 5, 6, 8, 18, 19, 20, 22]},
        {MonthNumber: 9, YearNumber: 2022, FlightDates: [1, 5, 6, 8, 13, 16, 19, 22]}
    ]
};

// Loope through API to find each month
for (let i=0; i < mm_newJson.Months.length; i++) {
  // Find fares which are available in month
  for (let j = 0; j < mm_newJson.Months[i].FlightDates.length; j++) {
    let obj = {};
    // Grab the specific dates
    obj['date'] = String(mm_newJson.Months[i].YearNumber) + '-' + String(('0' + String(mm_newJson.Months[i].MonthNumber)).slice(-2)) + '-' + String(('0' + (mm_newJson.Months[i].FlightDates[j])).slice(-2));
    obj['fare'] = "WW";
    mm_dailyPrice.push(obj);
  }
}

// Search mm_dailyPrice for date
function searchDate(input) {
  let object = mm_dailyPrice.find(el => el.date === input);

  if (object !== undefined)
    return object.fare;

    return false;
}


// Add AVAILABILITY
//let days = document.querySelector('div[data-tab*="Date Calendar Outbound"]').querySelectorAll('.day');
let days = [
    {dataset: {date: "2022-08-01"}},
    {dataset: {date: "2022-08-02"}},
    {dataset: {date: "2022-08-03"}},
    {dataset: {date: "2022-08-04"}},
    {dataset: {date: "2022-08-05"}},
    {dataset: {date: "2022-08-06"}},
    {dataset: {date: "2022-08-07"}},
    {dataset: {date: "2022-08-08"}},
    {dataset: {date: "2022-08-09"}},
    {dataset: {date: "2022-08-10"}},
    {dataset: {date: "2022-08-11"}},
    {dataset: {date: "2022-08-12"}},
    {dataset: {date: "2022-08-13"}},
    {dataset: {date: "2022-08-14"}},
    {dataset: {date: "2022-08-15"}},
    {dataset: {date: "2022-08-16"}},
    {dataset: {date: "2022-08-17"}},
    {dataset: {date: "2022-08-18"}},
    {dataset: {date: "2022-08-19"}},
    {dataset: {date: "2022-08-20"}},
    {dataset: {date: "2022-08-21"}},
    {dataset: {date: "2022-08-22"}},
    {dataset: {date: "2022-08-23"}},
    {dataset: {date: "2022-08-24"}},
    {dataset: {date: "2022-08-25"}},
    {dataset: {date: "2022-08-26"}},
    {dataset: {date: "2022-08-27"}},
    {dataset: {date: "2022-08-28"}},
    {dataset: {date: "2022-08-29"}},
    {dataset: {date: "2022-08-30"}}
];

let j = 0;

let list = document.querySelector(".list");
console.log(mm_newJson.Months[12]);

// For each day in the 12 month calendar, display the "fare" value
for (let i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
  let date = days[i].dataset.date;
  //if (days[i].firstElementChild){
    let fare = searchDate(date);

    if (fare !== false) {
      let priceSpan = document.createElement('span');
      priceSpan.innerHTML = "date " + date + ", fare " + String(fare);
      priceSpan.setAttribute('class', 'calendar-price-test');
      //days[j].appendChild(priceSpan);
      
      let item = document.createElement('li');
      item.appendChild(priceSpan);
      list.appendChild(item);
      
      //j++;
      console.log(j, "date", date, "fare", fare);
    }
  //}
}
```

```html
<ul class="list"></ul>
```

Instead, the error lies in the presentation, in using two different indexes `i` and `j` to specify from which calendar day to read the reference date (`i`) and on which calendar day to insert the `span` (`j`).

Since `j` is only incremented when searchDate does not return `undefined` you will always see all dates with WW consecutively.

---

As a side note I recommend that you modify the structure of the `mm_dailyPrice` array to have faster and easier access to the data.

You could use an object (dictionary) instead of an array and specify as keys the first part of the UTC date (YYYY-MM) or YYYY-MM-01 and as the value the array with the days of the month already returned by the API (and other optional data you can need) without scanning mm_dailyPrice every time.

I can't write you an example because I don't know how you will use the `fare` property.

Comment: Hi @Marco Sacchi, unfortunately, this injects "WW" into every day

https://ibb.co/HTMWcfd

I've also add a screenshot of the response, if that helps?

Comment: Thank you @Marco Sacchi - I was just taking a look at this.  Appreciate the time you gave to put this together and just rerunning your code.  Thank you very much!!

Comment: @ReenaVerma I'm glad to be helpful. But why did you assign the correct answer to the one that is not the correct answer? :)

Comment: @ReenaVerma, actually your question is not clear and I know what you try to do after reading your comment. I think you should accept this answer if it help you understand your question and solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry I thought I did accept it.  And apologies, I tried to make it as clear as I could, but there was a lot going on. Thank you all!  Could someone accept my answer too?

Comment: @MarcoSacchi - Because I still found it helpful :) Shall I not accept it?

Comment: @ReenaVerma - There is no need for an apology. But on stackoverflow only one answer can be marked as accepted (while more can be marked as useful) and, when there is more than one, the most complete and most useful one should be chosen, thinking also of other people who could find your question in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can set an if block, if the fare is not `"n/a"` , you can set the innerHTML.
Otherwise, you don't do anything about the innerHTML.

```js
if (fare !== "n/a") {
   priceSpan.innerHTML = String(fare);
}
```

Comment: @ikhvs Unfortunately, this returns the same issue :). https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UogR.png

Comment: @ReenaVerma, did you remove the `else` block in `searchDate` function ?

Comment: @ikvjs - No it still there.

function searchDate(input) {
  let object = mm_dailyPrice.find(el => el.date === input);
  // console.log("object", object)
  if (object != undefined) {
    console.log("object", object);
    return object.fare;
  } else {
    // Returns undefined, if I do not handle else condition
    return "n/a";
  }
};

Comment: @ReenaVerma, OK. I updated my answer. Please try again.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working!!! Thank you everyone for your help!!!

After updating the `searchDate` function, as suggested by Marco and declaring `(fare !== undefined)`, the fare was still appearing in all days, rather than just the specific ones.

I realised that I was not matching the `fare` date, with the date of the calendar day properly.  That's why "WW" or "n/a" was being injected into ALL days, instead of the specific days I needed.

So I updated `searchDate`, to return the whole object.  And then checked the objected date, matched the calendar month date, which I wanted to inject into.  And this seemed to work! :)

I can probably tidy this up, but just thought I'd let you know.

Thank you everyone for your help!  Which still helped me to form my final solution :)

```
window.mm_newJson = [];
window.mm_dailyPrice = [];
window.mm_fullDate = new Date();
window.mm_startDate = String(mm_fullDate.getFullYear()) + '-' + String(mm_fullDate.getMonth()+1) + '-' +  String(mm_fullDate.getDate());

// FETCH DATE AVAILABILITY
const response = await fetch('www.MYAPI.com');
mm_newJson = await response.json();

// Loope through API to find each month
for (let i=0; i < mm_newJson.Months.length; i++) {
  // Find fares which are available in month
  for (let j = 0; j < mm_newJson.Months[i].FlightDates.length; j++) {
    let obj = {};
    obj['date'] = String(mm_newJson.Months[i].YearNumber) + '-' + String(('0' + String(mm_newJson.Months[i].MonthNumber)).slice(-2)) + '-' + String(('0' + (mm_newJson.Months[i].FlightDates[j])).slice(-2));
    obj['fare'] = "WW";
    mm_dailyPrice.push(obj);
  };
};

// Search mm_dailyPrice for price
function searchDate(date) {
  let object = mm_dailyPrice.find(el => el.date === date);
  if (object != undefined) {
    return object;
  }
  return;
};

// Add AVAILABILITY
let days = document.querySelector('div[data-tab*="Date Calendar Outbound"]').querySelectorAll('.day');
let j = 0;

// For each day in the 12 month calendar, display the "fare" value
for (let i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
  console.log("days", days[i].dataset); // DOMStringMap {date: "2021-08-01"}

  let date = days[i].dataset.date;
  console.log("date", date); // date 2021-08-02

  if (days[i].firstElementChild){
    let objFinal = searchDate(date);

    if (objFinal !== undefined) {
      if (days[i].attributes[1].value === objFinal.date) {
        console.log("days[i].attributes[1].value", days[i].attributes[1].value); //the matching days are returned
        let priceSpan = document.createElement('span');
        priceSpan.innerHTML = String(objFinal.fare);
        priceSpan.setAttribute('class', 'calendar-price-test');
        days[i].appendChild(priceSpan);
      }
    }
  }
};
```